# Using a class like a public variable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, scope

I'm getting an error in .net when trying to declare a Public class on my code behind page.

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public someVariable as integer
    Public someClass as className

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load [...]
```

The error I'm getting is  `BC30508: 'someClass' cannot expose type 'className' in namespace '<Default>' through class '_Default'.`

The goal here is accessing the class properties in script blocks on the aspx page like this `<%=someClass.classProperty%>`

I'm not sure if I'm trying the right methods (I've tried several ways of declaring the public class) or if it can even be done... Thanks for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the protection level of your `className` type.  Did you forget to mark it public?

That error message means you have something that is has restricted access, and you are trying to use it in a way that would allow access outside the restrictions.  For example, if your `className` type is `internal` or a `private` child class of `_Default`, but you add a public member of that type as a property your assembly would expose a type as part of it's interface that is otherwise unusable.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly the declaration of your "className" class.  Try setting it to public.

Answer (score 0):

Check the protection level of the _Default class. It might not be setup as a partial class and that will result in your protection level issue that you are seeing.

Comment: His posted sample includes "Partial"